# Min-height:100vh is not working for my project

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am not doing anything new, nothing I haven't done before yet I have this issue. I would love for someone to explain why I even have a scrollbar at this point, why isn't min-height: 100vh; working? I mean I've tried 4 different methods from solutions on overflow it's still present in the code as well.

```css
.title {
  font-family: "Laterlocks DEMO";
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 133px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #bf787c, #96a1a3 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

:root {
  --bg-grey: #e9e9e9;
  /*#96A1A3;
      #bf787c; 
      #ddacb2;
*/
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-grey);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

img.bookcover {
  height: 700px;
  width: 494px;
}

.hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.herogrid-container {
  max-width: 1250px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 180px;
  gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main class="hero">
  <div class="herogrid-container">
    <div class="heroinner left">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/36IzNn5.jpg" alt="MPD Psycho Book Cover" class="bookcover">
    </div>
    <div class="heroinner right">
      <p class="title">MPD PSCYHO</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**What I tried**

```
  min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
```

[My codepen](https://codepen.io/lilliongoddess/pen/xxEmXVY?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

I cant find why your way doesnt work. But this is a working way to get what you want.

```css
.title {
    font-family: "Laterlocks DEMO";
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 133px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #bf787c, #96a1a3 70%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

:root {
    --bg-grey: #e9e9e9;
    /*#96A1A3;
      #bf787c; 
      #ddacb2;
*/
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-grey);
}

img.bookcover {
    display: block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 494px;
}
.hero {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10vw;
}
.herogrid-container {
    max-width: 1250px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <main class="hero">
     <div class="herogrid-container">
      <div class="heroinner left">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/36IzNn5.jpg" alt="MPD Psycho Book Cover" class="bookcover">
      </div>
      <div class="heroinner right">
      <p class="title">MPD PSCYHO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </main>
```

Comment: Please add a sufficient explantion on what you did. An anwser without any explanation is low-quality. It is hard to udnerstand and therefor also ahrd to reproduce as a possible solution.

Comment: the issue why it is not working is, that the height of the ehader is 5% with a padding of 20px. Means the paddings alone will require 40px of space. for HD screen, 5% vh translate into ~16px height. As such the header is at least 24px to high and causing an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` element has a default `margin: 8px`.

The `herogrid-container` element has a `margin-top: 180px`.

Try working with those. Setting them to `0` helps.

The `width: 494px` on `.img-bookcover` is also generating a vertical scroll. Not sure how you want to handle that, but removing that rule solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Find a **reset.css** file.
Browsers come with default styling and a reset.css file will get rid of those for you. I replaced my index.css so I could design from scratch.